# How to get XML node by ID and NamedNodeMap - Java DOM XML

Tags: java, xml, dom

I have an xml file with messages:

```
<bus>
    <message id="58afdb36-9080-4dd8-922e-ee516b2b5073">
    <retrievedDate>Mon Feb 18 14:43:23 GMT 2013</retrievedDate>
    <addedDate>Mon Feb 18 14:43:23 GMT 2013</addedDate>
    <state>initialised</state>
    <content>content placeholder</content>
    </message>
</bus>
```

I am creating a method to change the state of a message for a given ID.

However I keep getting NullPointerException when I try to get the node with the ID I want. Have tried experimenting with ***getElementById*** and ***getElementsByTagName***, but I always get null instead of the node I want.

```
public static int updateMessageState(UUID messageID, String newState) 
        throws ParserConfigurationException, 
                SAXException, IOException, TransformerException {

    String filepath = "data.xml";
    DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = docBuilder.parse(filepath);

    // Get Message
    Node message = doc.getElementById(messageID.toString());

    // Find and update the state
    NamedNodeMap atrMap = message.getAttributes();
    Node nodeAtr = atrMap.getNamedItem("state");
    nodeAtr.setTextContent(newState);

    // Save write to XML
    TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
    DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
    StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File(filepath));
    transformer.transform(source, result);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: `NamedNodeMap atrMap = message.getAttributes();` will find the attributes of the message tag, but "state" is an sibling *element* of the message tag.  You will need to get `message.getParentNode().getChildNodes()` and iterate until you find the "state" tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `getElementById()` you must make sure that the **type** of the attribute "id" is `ID` or else null will be returned from the method. See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html#getElementById%28java.lang.String%29).

I don't see an example of how you are using `getElementsByTagName(String str)` so I will provide an example. When using `getElementsByTagName()` you will actually get a `NodeList` corresponding to the elements which have the tag. In your example you would use `doc.getElementsByName("message")` in order to retrieve a node list of the message elements. You can then use the node list to then find what you are looking for.

Comment: how can i define my id attribute to be of type ID?

Answer (score 1):

You can get Id using Element:

```
// Get the main element by tag name
Node bus = doc.getElementsByTagName("bus").item(0);

//get a NodeList
NodeList list = bus.getChildNodes();
for (int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++) {
    Node node = list.item(i);
    System.out.println("\nCurrent Element :" + node.getNodeName());
    if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
        Element eElement = (Element) node;
        System.out.println(" id : " + eElement.getAttribute("id"));
    }
}
```